# Discord.Client is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, discord, discord.js

**I am using discord.js 12.3.0 webpack**

This is my code so far

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    const Discord = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/discordjs/discord.js/webpack/discord.12.3.0.min.js');
      const client = new Discord.Client();
    
      client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
      });
    
      client.login('. . .');
    </script>
```

My goal is to have the website show all of the bot's information, but I can't log in with the bot.

This is my error:

```js
index.html:12 Uncaught TypeError: Discord.Client is not a constructor
    at index.html:12
(anonymous) @ index.html:12

index.html:8 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://raw.githubusercontent.com/discordjs/discord.js/webpack/discord.12.3.0.min.js with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the CORS problem.
Try `<script src="..."></script>`